# Decomposition of the homogeneous polynomial ring $\{\mathbb R[x_{ij}]_{1\le i,j\le n}\}$ of degree 2 into Specht modules

Tags: rt.representation-theory, symmetry

I have tried to decompose this as following spans over the real field.

$V_1=\operatorname{span} \langle x_{ij}^2\rangle$

$V_2=\operatorname{span} \langle x_{ij}x_{jk}\rangle$

$V_3=\operatorname{span} \langle x_{ij}x_{kl}\rangle$

where the index $ij$ stands for the subset $\{i,j\}$ of size 2, thus the ordering within does not matter and there are no variables of the form $x_{ii}$. Also the indices $i,j,k,l$ are distinct.

Now, one determines

$V_1\cong M_{(n-2,2)}$
$V_2\cong M_{(n-3,2,1)}$

Next I tried for $V_3$ the following:

$E_{il,jk}=x_{ij}x_{kl}+x_{ik}x_{jl}$ is fixed precisely by the group $S_{i,l}\times S_{j,k}\times S_{n-4}$.

Moreover, $E_{il,jk}-E_{ij,kl}+E_{ik,jl}=2x_{ij}x_{kl}$, which shows that all of $V_3$ is generated. One can define a map $\phi:M_{(n-4,2,2)}\rightarrow V_3$ by sending the tabloid with last two rows $i,j$ followed by $k,l$, to the element $E_{ij,kl}$. One can get deceived into concluding that this is an isomorphism.

Unfortunately since the tabloid with rows $k,l$ and $i,j$ above swapped also maps to $x_{ij}x_{kl}$, this map is not an isomorphism.

However $x_{ij}x_{kl}+x_{ik}x_{jl}+x_{il}x_{jk}$ has fixed group $S_{(n-4,4)}$ and is isomorphic to $M_{(n-4,4)}$, so I know that this makes up ${n\choose 4}$ dimensions in $V_3$, but a dimension count shows that the remaining $2{n\choose 4}$ dimensions has many possible decompositions into Specht modules.

Could someone help with zeroing in on one decomposition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $W_4$ for the $S_4$ representation $$({\rm Ind}_{S_2 \times S_2}^{S_4} ({\rm triv} \otimes {\rm triv}))_{S_2}.$$
Then similarly to the answer to your previous question, you are considering $$Ind^{S_{n}}_{S_4 \times S_{n-4}} (W_4 \otimes {\rm triv}),$$ which can be computed using the Pieri rule as soon as you know the decomposition of $W_4$ into irreducibles.

By definition $W_4$ corresponds to the plethysm $(2) \circ (2)$.  In general, plethysm is hard to compute but any specific case can be done,  and in fact the plethysm $(n) \circ (2)$ is known in general.  This should allow you to compute $(x_{i_1 j_1}) \dots (x_{i_n j_n})$ where all indices are distinct.

We have $(2) \circ (2) = (4) + (2,2)$.  So the answer is $$((4) + (2,2))*(n-4)$$ $$ = (n) + (n-1,1) + (n-2,2) + (n-3,3) + (n-4,4)$$   $$+ (n-2,2) + (n-3,2,1) + (n-4,2,2).$$

Comment: I think we should have $(n-1,1)$ and $(n-3,3)$ as everything adds to $n$. I wonder if we can write an explicit basis for each irreducible? I can do the trivial :). You can get sub representations doing things like like fix $i,j$ then look at $\sum_{k, \ell} x_{ij}x_{k\ell}$.

Comment: @John Thanks-- fixed the typo.   It should be possible, since you can decompose $W_4$ easily  (but I don't know the answer).

Comment: @PhilTosteson, what is a good reference article/book for the Plethysm computation? Googling doesn't seem to do much good. Also Sagan's book's index does not have the word Plethysm.

Comment: @PhilTosteson, does the subscript $_{S_2}$ at the end of the second line mean something? Otherwise I see no reason why $(3,1)$ doesn't appear in the expansion of the Plethysm $(2)\circ(2)$.

Comment: @Karthik Yes, it means take co-invariants with respect to the action of $S_2$.  In other words $W_4$ is the action of $S_4$ on partitions into two blocks of size two.   For this specific case, there is no need to learn about plethysm-- the decomposition is easy.   If you're interested in learning more, I would reccomend Stanley's enumerative combinatorics volume 2.

Comment: Muchos Gracias senor @Phil ! Much appreciated. This problem or class of problems was one roadblock I'd been trying to clear but hadn't had even an elementary understanding of symmetry group reps. I look forward to more interactions in future!